# Using tapply to calculate group means but can't identify the groups from the output (the group variables are characters)

Tags: r

I'm using tapply to calculate group means but I can't get from the output what those groupings are. The grouping is combination of two variables, Var1 and Var2. It would be easier to demonstrate with some code

```
set.seed(123)
df <- mtcars
df$VAR1 <- sample(c("A","B"), nrow(mtcars) , replace = TRUE)
df$VAR2 <- sample(c("X","Y"), nrow(mtcars) , replace = TRUE)
df_result <- data.frame(apply(df[,sapply(df,is.numeric)], 2, function(x) tapply(x, list(df$VAR1,df$VAR2),mean)) )
```

the output

```
> df_result
      mpg cyl     disp     hp    drat       wt     qsec    vs  am gear  carb
1 22.3800 5.8 194.0500 126.80 3.74900 2.803000 18.44600 0.500 0.5 3.70 2.100
2 17.9900 6.8 284.0700 162.70 3.19900 3.645300 17.82700 0.400 0.2 3.30 2.600
3 18.9125 6.5 252.7875 168.50 3.74375 3.366125 17.16625 0.375 0.5 3.75 3.625
4 21.9750 5.0 144.9000 112.75 3.91500 2.885000 17.77500 0.500 0.5 4.50 3.500
```

As you can see I can't tell which row is which combination of Var1 and Var2. The 4 groups should be A-X, A-Y, B-X, B-Y. Does anyone know how to add that table? Any modifications or simplification to the code would be ideal. Is it even possible?
Yes, I know it can be done more simply with "dplyr" and "aggregate", however I want to use sapply/tapply/lapply in some way to do this. Please simplify if i'm doing something wrong. Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Use `aggregate` - `aggregate(.~VAR1 + VAR2, df, mean)`

Comment: Thanks, but I already mentioned in post, I was looking for a way not to use aggregate or dplyr methods. I want to do it via the apply family. If it's not possible then it would good to know also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, I don't think this is the right problem to use the apply family of functions. If you want to learn about them there are various other examples that you can use.

Functions like `aggregate` are built for this -

```
aggregate(.~VAR1 + VAR2, df, mean)
```

Obviously, you can cut a paper with a sword but that is not what it is made for. Here's using `tapply` -

```
tmp <- unique(df[c('VAR1', 'VAR2')])
rownames(tmp) <- NULL

cbind(tmp[with(tmp, order(VAR2, VAR1)), ], 
      sapply(df[,sapply(df,is.numeric)], function(x) 
      tapply(x, list(df$VAR1,df$VAR2),mean)))
```

Comment: I tried using the aggregate(.~VAR1 + VAR2, df, mean) you suggested. But it doesn't work if I replace mean with  weighted.mean(x, wgt, na.rm = TRUE)  . is there  reason why I can't use this function with aggregate? if this is off topic i'll open up another question. thanks

Comment: Yes, `aggregate` doesn't have access to other variables by group. In such case, I use `dplyr` which is flexible in this case. If you want to stick with base R, you can use `split` + `lapply` to do it.

Answer (score 1):

This should you get closer to what you want. (Not using `tapply` though.) You could use `outer()` to apply custom `Vectorize`d functions to combinations of `"VAR1"` and `"VAR2"`. We also use `outer` with `paste` to identify the combinations.

```
v <- lapply(df[, c('VAR1', 'VAR2')], unique)  ## get levels

nm <- c("mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp", "drat", "wt", "qsec", "vs", "am", 
        "gear", "carb")  ## vector of columns to loop over
```

For the `mean` we may apply `colMeans` on columns subset `nm`.

```
V_MEAN <- Vectorize(\(x, y) colMeans(df[df$VAR1 == x & df$VAR2 == y, nm]), 
                    SIMPLIFY=F)
    
sapply(outer(v[[1]], v[[2]], V_MEAN), I) |> 
  `colnames<-`(outer(v[[1]], v[[2]], paste, sep='_'))
#          A_X      B_X        A_Y     B_Y
# mpg   22.380  17.9900  18.912500  21.975
# cyl    5.800   6.8000   6.500000   5.000
# disp 194.050 284.0700 252.787500 144.900
# hp   126.800 162.7000 168.500000 112.750
# drat   3.749   3.1990   3.743750   3.915
# wt     2.803   3.6453   3.366125   2.885
# qsec  18.446  17.8270  17.166250  17.775
# vs     0.500   0.4000   0.375000   0.500
# am     0.500   0.2000   0.500000   0.500
# gear   3.700   3.3000   3.750000   4.500
# carb   2.100   2.6000   3.625000   3.500
```

For `weighted.mean`, we use an anonymous function in an `sapply`, where we define the `w=`.

```
set.seed(42)
df$wgt <- runif(nrow(df))  ## fabricate weights


V_W_MEAN <- Vectorize(\(x, y) {
  dat <- df[df$VAR1 == x & df$VAR2 == y, ]
  sapply(dat[, nm], \(z) weighted.mean(z, w=dat[, 'wgt']))
}, SIMPLIFY=F)

sapply(outer(v[[1]], v[[2]], V_W_MEAN), I) |> 
  `colnames<-`(outer(v[[1]], v[[2]], paste, sep='_'))
#              A_X         B_X         A_Y         B_Y
# mpg   21.4040177  18.7455432  17.4546812  20.9215362
# cyl    5.8600143   6.6403719   6.7614803   5.4227808
# disp 199.3270864 274.2125329 264.9109708 145.5146065
# hp   125.5585798 164.2029158 183.3016365 135.5210857
# drat   3.7055945   3.2798961   3.7334560   3.8744869
# wt     2.8267939   3.5926588   3.5684028   2.8345649
# qsec  18.4069666  17.8164896  16.9251482  16.9464657
# vs     0.4587740   0.4358106   0.2869283   0.3257468
# am     0.4255709   0.2440034   0.4766754   0.6742532
# gear   3.6095371   3.3727337   3.7589968   4.6742532
# carb   2.1471308   2.6620944   4.1912125   4.3421659
```

If you prefer lists as result, you can use `lapply(outer...) |> setNames(outer(...))`.

**Note:** `"R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)"`

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(mpg = c(21, 21, 22.8, 21.4, 18.7, 18.1, 14.3, 
24.4, 22.8, 19.2, 17.8, 16.4, 17.3, 15.2, 10.4, 10.4, 14.7, 32.4, 
30.4, 33.9, 21.5, 15.5, 15.2, 13.3, 19.2, 27.3, 26, 30.4, 15.8, 
19.7, 15, 21.4), cyl = c(6, 6, 4, 6, 8, 6, 8, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 
8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 8, 6, 8, 4), 
    disp = c(160, 160, 108, 258, 360, 225, 360, 146.7, 140.8, 
    167.6, 167.6, 275.8, 275.8, 275.8, 472, 460, 440, 78.7, 75.7, 
    71.1, 120.1, 318, 304, 350, 400, 79, 120.3, 95.1, 351, 145, 
    301, 121), hp = c(110, 110, 93, 110, 175, 105, 245, 62, 95, 
    123, 123, 180, 180, 180, 205, 215, 230, 66, 52, 65, 97, 150, 
    150, 245, 175, 66, 91, 113, 264, 175, 335, 109), drat = c(3.9, 
    3.9, 3.85, 3.08, 3.15, 2.76, 3.21, 3.69, 3.92, 3.92, 3.92, 
    3.07, 3.07, 3.07, 2.93, 3, 3.23, 4.08, 4.93, 4.22, 3.7, 2.76, 
    3.15, 3.73, 3.08, 4.08, 4.43, 3.77, 4.22, 3.62, 3.54, 4.11
    ), wt = c(2.62, 2.875, 2.32, 3.215, 3.44, 3.46, 3.57, 3.19, 
    3.15, 3.44, 3.44, 4.07, 3.73, 3.78, 5.25, 5.424, 5.345, 2.2, 
    1.615, 1.835, 2.465, 3.52, 3.435, 3.84, 3.845, 1.935, 2.14, 
    1.513, 3.17, 2.77, 3.57, 2.78), qsec = c(16.46, 17.02, 18.61, 
    19.44, 17.02, 20.22, 15.84, 20, 22.9, 18.3, 18.9, 17.4, 17.6, 
    18, 17.98, 17.82, 17.42, 19.47, 18.52, 19.9, 20.01, 16.87, 
    17.3, 15.41, 17.05, 18.9, 16.7, 16.9, 14.5, 15.5, 14.6, 18.6
    ), vs = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), am = c(1, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), gear = c(4, 4, 4, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4), carb = c(4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 
    2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 1, 
    2, 2, 4, 6, 8, 2), VAR1 = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B", 
    "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "B", 
    "A", "B"), VAR2 = c("X", "Y", "Y", "X", "X", "X", "X", "Y", 
    "X", "Y", "Y", "X", "X", "X", "X", "Y", "X", "X", "Y", "X", 
    "X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "X", "Y", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "X"
    )), row.names = c("Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag", "Datsun 710", 
"Hornet 4 Drive", "Hornet Sportabout", "Valiant", "Duster 360", 
"Merc 240D", "Merc 230", "Merc 280", "Merc 280C", "Merc 450SE", 
"Merc 450SL", "Merc 450SLC", "Cadillac Fleetwood", "Lincoln Continental", 
"Chrysler Imperial", "Fiat 128", "Honda Civic", "Toyota Corolla", 
"Toyota Corona", "Dodge Challenger", "AMC Javelin", "Camaro Z28", 
"Pontiac Firebird", "Fiat X1-9", "Porsche 914-2", "Lotus Europa", 
"Ford Pantera L", "Ferrari Dino", "Maserati Bora", "Volvo 142E"
), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

In the comments you add that you want to use `weighted.mean`. Here's one way using `by` - a function which was a lifesaver before `dplyr` came along.

```r
result <- by(df[1:10], list(df$VAR1, df$VAR2), \(x) apply(x, 2, weighted.mean, w = x$cyl))
```

This returns a list of class `by`, which has a `dim` attribute of `c(2, 2)` and the `dimnames()` are the values of your factors. It prints out nicely:

```r
> result
: A
: X
        mpg         cyl        disp          hp        drat          wt        qsec          vs 
 20.6344828   6.4137931 228.3655172 144.2758621   3.6572414   2.9768966  17.8972414   0.3448276 
         am        gear 
  0.4482759   3.6551724 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
: B
: X
        mpg         cyl        disp          hp        drat          wt        qsec          vs 
 16.9558824   7.1764706 307.2823529 172.0294118   3.1282353   3.8397353  17.7182353   0.2941176 
         am        gear 
  0.1176471   3.1764706 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
: A
: Y
        mpg         cyl        disp          hp        drat          wt        qsec          vs 
 17.6384615   6.9230769 284.3923077 187.2692308   3.6315385   3.5973462  16.9130769   0.2692308 
         am        gear 
  0.4230769   3.6923077 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
: B
: Y
    mpg     cyl    disp      hp    drat      wt    qsec      vs      am    gear 
 21.330   5.200 147.180 120.000   3.886   2.929  17.660   0.500   0.500   4.500
```